# R: pivot_wider() to extend a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyr

I am having some issues ranslating a dataframe into wide format using pivot_wider. My dataframe looks like this:

```
Data <- read.table(header = T, text = "
        ID  A         B           C           D
         1  6.01764 0.00409222  0.000500143 101.816
         1  6.01769 0.00431931  0.000565946 101.334
         1  6.01774 0.00454617  0.00063163  101.923
         2  6.01779 0.00477308  0.000697374 101.914
         2  6.01784 0.00500005  0.000763118 101.905
         2  6.0179  0.00522703  0.000828803 101.926
         3  6.01795 0.005454    0.000894606 101.889
         3  6.018   0.00568086  0.000960231 101.895
         3  6.01805 0.00590783  0.00102603  101.87
")
```

I would like to create unique column names by combining The "ID" with the Column name so that it looks like this:

```
Datalong <- read.table(header = T, text = "
1A  1B  1C  1D  2A  2B  2C  2D  3A  3B  3C  3D
6.01764 0.00409222  0.000500143 101.816 6.01779 0.00477308  0.000697374 101.914 6.01795 0.005454    0.000894606 101.889
6.01769 0.00431931  0.000565946 101.334 6.01784 0.00500005  0.000763118 101.905 6.018   0.00568086  0.000960231 101.895
6.01774 0.00454617  0.00063163  101.923 6.0179  0.00522703  0.000828803 101.926 6.01805 0.00590783  0.00102603  101.87
")
```

I am thinking I might need to add a new column that counts each instance of the ID column (as it is time series data)

I have tried:

```
DataNew <- Data %>% pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = c(ID, colnames(Data)))
```

And

```
Data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(time = row_number()) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = c(ID, colnames(Data)))
```

but to no avail. Any support would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add your data in the proper format!

Comment: Apologies - its updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
DataNew <- Data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to="var", values_to="vals") %>% 
  group_by(ID, var) %>% 
  mutate(obs =1:n(), 
         vnames = paste0(ID, var)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-c(ID, var)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = vnames, values_from = vals) %>% 
  select(-obs)

DataNew
# # A tibble: 3 x 12
#   `1A`    `1B`    `1C`  `1D`  `2A`    `2B`    `2C`  `2D`  `3A`    `3B`
#   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1  6.02 0.00409 5.00e-4  102.  6.02 0.00477 6.97e-4  102.  6.02 0.00545
# 2  6.02 0.00432 5.66e-4  101.  6.02 0.00500 7.63e-4  102.  6.02 0.00568
# 3  6.02 0.00455 6.32e-4  102.  6.02 0.00523 8.29e-4  102.  6.02 0.00591
# # … with 2 more variables: `3C` <dbl>, `3D` <dbl>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly Dave. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(Data), rowid(ID) ~ ID, value.var = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
```